Is there a way to localize Swagger api endpoints in Nestjs?
I have a simple Nest JS application. I have several endpoints, and I have documented them using Swagger. Below is a code snippet:
@Get()
  @ApiQuery({ name: 'search', required: false, description: 'Search term to filter items' })
  @ApiQuery({ name: 'limit', required: false, description: 'Number of items to return', type: Number })
  getItems(
    @Query('search') search?: string,
    @Query('limit') limit?: number,
  ) {
    // Endpoint logic here
    return this.carService.find(request);
  }

Now, what I'm wondering is: is it possible to localize the description values of the @ApiQuery decorators? I want those descriptions to appear either in English or Spanish on my Swagger UI.
I tried internationalizing the strings (using an I18n library) and passing the values to the decorators dynamically, but apparently, you can't do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Actually, there a few ways. One easy is offered by NestJS with the following package. nestjs-i18n
Steps:

Install the package with:
npm i nestjs-i18n

Now, you can write in your chosen language as your code example below(Spanish).
@Get()
@ApiQuery({ name: 'search', required: false, description: 'Término de búsqueda para filtrar elementos' })
@ApiQuery({ name: 'limit', required: false, description: 'Número de artículos a devolver', type: Number })
getItems(
    @Query('search') search?: string,
    @Query('limit') limit?: number,
) {
    return this.carService.find(request);
}



